# How can I add a image inside a title tag of an html element using just angular 2?

Tags: angular

I tried to add a image inside a title tag using this code:

```
<a click="selectCompanie(companie)" [title]="getImageTitle(companie)">
                   image name
</a>
```

```
getImageTitle(companie){
     debugger;
     return ``<img src="${companie.logoSrc}" class="companie-logo" />`;
}
```

but after the dom is rendered I have the image tag inside the title
element as a plain text. How can I add this?

Comment: You can't, only text is permitted: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/title

Answer (score 1):

use `innerHTML` to generating `img` tag inside anchor tag.

```
[innerHTML]="getImageTitle(companie)"
```

Comment: sorry for missleading I don't want it inside the anchor, I want it inside the title tag of the anchor

Comment: @Nicu you should use `popover`/`tooltip` then..in which you could specify template with custom HTML